# Unabled to get width() of the first column in table

Tags: jquery

I need to get a width of the first column in my table. I do the following:

```
var table = $(".myTable");
var firstColumnWidth = table.find("th:first").innerWidth();
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="">
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>col 2</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

I get "0", even though when I add  a border while debugging, I see it at least 300px wide.

```
table.find("th:first").css("border","1px solid red");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `width()` give you a valid result, or not?

Comment: How do I check? What do you mean valid result? I tried width() and innerWidth() -- same result: 0. I think it has something to do with document load, because if I click on another link that refreshes the page, everything works file...

Comment: It's a simple table. The problem is that I can add a border and see table cell being > 0...

Comment: @santa that's what I meant, width also produces 0...

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem. I get `131px` using either method:

`$('.table th:first-child').width()`

Your style is also being me the same output

`$('.table').find('th:first-child').width()`

Here is my markup

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>sdfsdfdsfasdsdd</th>
        <th>dsfdsfds</th>
        <th>sdfds</th>
        <th>hgthrhdgdfgdf</th>
        <th>fdgdfgdf</th>
        <th>fdgdfgdf</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fdgfdgdfgdfg</td>
        <td>fgh5hfhgdf</td>
        <td>dfgfdgdf</td>
        <td>dfgdfgdf</td>
        <td>dfgdfgdf</td>
        <td>dfgdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fdghtfg</td>
        <td>dfgfdgdfg</td>
        <td>fgdf</td>
        <td>dgfg</td>
        <td>fg</td>
        <td>ddddddddddd</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('.myTable').find('tr:first').width()`. This is because the browser renders `<td>` inside `<tr>` even though you use `<th>`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W8ejn/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/McLW6/1/)**

```
var table = $(".myTable");
var firstColumnWidth = table.find("th:first").innerWidth();
alert(firstColumnWidth);
alert(table.find("th:first").width());
```

For both **`.innerWidth()`** and **`.width()`** gives result as **`128`**

Comment: Yes, I would expect the same results... I am starting to think that I am getting such results because my table is generated dynamically and I may get the first cell before there's anything in it. I need to grab the first cell of the second row.